# Tornado Web Production Environment

Tags: python, security, debian, tornado

I just set up a simple virtual server with Debian netinst. Now I want to use the tornado webserver to host a public website. I am quite new to Linux so I don't know how to set up a secure server environment.

1. Which users do I need to create?
2. Which config changes do I need to do to get a secure system?
3. How should I run my tornado server (deamon, init.d, ... I don't know these methods...)?
4. Are there more things I need to take care of when setting up a server from scratch?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can create www user just as deploying LAMP environment
2. lock the www user in website directory
3. Supervisor is a good solution of running several tornado process
4. You can use nginx as front-end of your tornado server.

Comment: Could you maybe provide a link to a tutorial on how to get the first 2 steps done? Thanks a lot.